# Do more than half of Ontario residents believe that "mainstream" Islamic doctrines promote violence?

Tags: religion, islam, canada

In its article about the recent shootings in Quebec City, the [New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/01/29/world/americas/quebec-city-mosque-shooting-canada.html?_r=0) reported that:

> A survey in Ontario last summer found that while there was widespread support for accepting the refugees, only a third of respondents had a positive impression of Islam, and more than half felt its mainstream doctrines promoted violence.

As a Muslim living in Toronto, this kind of scares me. I don't want to believe it. I'm also posting anonymously because I don't want my identity revealed.

Is this true? Is there a credible source that proves this?

Answer (score 2):

The survey was never published. According to [The future of religious literacy and teacher education in the Ontario
classroom](https://www.religiouseducation.net/papers/rea2016-chan.pdf):

> A 51-page survey on this topic was released by the Ontario Council of
> Agencies Serving  Immigrants (OCASI) and Mass Minority, an advocacy
> group; however, after a newspaper article published by Nicholas Keung
> raised this matter
>
> (https://www.thestar.com/news/immigration/2016/07/04/ontario-facing-epidemic-of-islamophobia-survey-finds.html),
> the province and the City of Toronto contacted OCASI to  postpone the
> official release of the findings. This detail was shared by Keung via
> an email  conversation on July 14, 2016.

The Star article it links to says,

> The survey by polling firm MARU/VCR&C measured public perceptions of
> ethnicity and immigration in Ontario in the wake of the recent influx
> of thousands of Syrian refugees — almost 12,000 to this province
> alone.
>
> “There is an epidemic of Islamophobia in Ontario. Only a third of
> Ontarians have a positive impression of the religion and more than
> half feel its mainstream doctrines promote violence (an anomaly
> compared to other religions),” said the 51-page survey to be released
> this week by the Ontario Council of Agencies Serving Immigrants and
> advocacy group Mass Minority. “These sentiments are echoed with Syrian
> refugees in Ontario where acceptance often coincides with acceptance
> of Islam.”
>
> Ontario has seen a number of recent incidents targeting Muslims. A
> woman wearing a hijab was attacked at a supermarket in London in June
> and a Western University student from Iran was beaten by two men who
> taunted him and told him to go back to his country. Also, in June, an
> anti-immigrant group rooted in Germany held an anti-Muslim protest in
> Toronto.
>
> [Source](https://www.thestar.com/news/immigration/2016/07/04/ontario-facing-epidemic-of-islamophobia-survey-finds.html)

Comment: Did the poll break out how many of Ontario muslims believe mainstream Islamic doctrines promote violence or countenance Jihad or Sharia?

Answer (score -1):

The poll appears to have been the subject of press coverage in July 2016 (see [The Star](https://www.thestar.com/news/immigration/2016/07/04/ontario-facing-epidemic-of-islamophobia-survey-finds.html), [The Express Tribune](https://tribune.com.pk/story/1136815/ontario-facing-epidemic-islamophobia-survey-finds/) and [Full Report](http://www.fullreport.ca/poll-finds-that-a-large-number-of-people-in-ontario-dont-trust-muslim-refugees/) from 4, 8 and 10 July respectively). These articles are almost verbatim copies and seem to be a media echo chamber - they also appear to be the source of the New York Time's coverage.

They all refer to the survey being prepared by "the [Ontario Council of Agencies Serving Immigrants](http://www.ocasi.org/) and advocacy group [Mass Minority](http://www.massminority.com/)" that "will be" released, however, I cannot find the "51 page survey" on either organisation's website. You may want to contact them and ask for a copy of the survey and the data set.